# DEC2Bin in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, input, hex, bin

So, I have an input set for users to enter some Integer characters. I next need to change this Integer (Decimal) into binary on submit in Javascript. I want the binary to be displayed in a text input different to the hex data. I have pasted the input code below. How could this be done ? thanks!

```html
<input type="text" id="HEXBit" />
<label for="HEXBit">Input the HEX Bitmask Here.</label>
<input type="submit" id="Submit" onclick="hex2bin();" />

<input type="text" id="BINARYBit" />
```

Comment: How do you  want to display "binary" exactly?

Comment: just as 0 and 1, in the input with ID of BINARYBit

Comment: Ah, so you want a 0/1 based *binary representation*. In essence, you want a *base converter* from base 16 to base 2.(?)

Comment: Yeah thats it, shouldve put that in the question!

Comment: That's not binary. That's base 2.

Answer (score 4):

Base conversion in Javascript from base 16 to base 2:

```
parseInt('ABCDEF', 16).toString(2)
// 101010111100110111101111
```